# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre char name[] y char* name en C?

Tags: c

Alguien puede explicarme cual es la diferencia entre:

```
char* name = "Gerardo";
```

o

```
char name[] = "Gerardo";
```

Me gustaría saber las diferencias en términos de memoria o performance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Una diferencia fundamental es que en el caso del puntero se apunta a un literal cadena de caracteres. Intentar modificarla es comportamiento indefinido.

Mientras que en el otro caso el array contiene una copia de la cadena que sí es modificable.

El hecho de que un literal de cadena no sea modificable permite a los compiladores hacer ciertas optimizaciones. Si una cadena está repetida en el código y se utiliza como un literal el compilador puede utilizar la misma copia de la cadena para todos los usos, reduciendo el uso de memoria. Además se puede usar directamente, lo cual es más rápido.

Por ejemplo, este programa en C :

```
#include<stdio.h>
void f() {
  char* name = "Gerardo";
  puts(name);
}

int main(void) {
  char* name = "Gerardo";
  puts(name);
  return 0;
}
```

El código ensamblador compilado (dejando solo las partes relevantes) :

```
.LC0:
        .string "Gerardo"     <----- Aparece solo una vez
        .section        .text.unlikely,"ax",@progbits

f:
.LFB23:
        .cfi_startproc
        movl    $.LC0, %edi <---- Ponemos la dirección de la cadena en edi
        jmp     puts        <---- Y puts usa la cadena desde ahí directamente
        .cfi_endproc

main:
.LFB24:
        .cfi_startproc
        subq    $8, %rsp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        movl    $.LC0, %edi   <------- Main usa la misma cadena
        call    puts
```

Sin embargo el mismo programa usando arrays :

```
void f() {
  char name[] = "Gerardo";
  puts(name);
}
int main(void) {
  char name[] = "Gerardo";
  puts(name);
  return 0;
}
```

Al compilarlo :

```
f:
.LFB23:
        .cfi_startproc
        subq    $24, %rsp          <----- Hay que reservar espacio en la pila
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32     
        movq    %fs:40, %rax
        movq    %rax, 8(%rsp)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movq    %rsp, %rdi
        movabsq $31354164838819143, %rax <--- Hay que copiar la cadena a la pila;
                                         <--- Esto lleva tiempo y ocupa espacio
        movq    %rax, (%rsp)
        call    puts

main:
.LFB24:
        .cfi_startproc
        subq    $24, %rsp           <------ Reservando espacio en la pila
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 32
        movq    %fs:40, %rax
        movq    %rax, 8(%rsp)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movq    %rsp, %rdi
        movabsq $31354164838819143, %rax  <--- Gerardo está 2 veces en el binario
        movq    %rax, (%rsp)
        call    puts
```

Para compilar esos ejemplos he usado `gcc -c -S -O2 fichero.c` (versión 5.4.0)

**Conclusión**. Si no vas a modificar la cadena es más rápido y gasta menos memoria la alternativa del literal de cadena asignado a un puntero. Si vas a modificar la cadena debes usar el array.

Answer (score 4):

Los punteros de carácter se utilizan normalmente para acceder a cadenas de caracteres, puesto que éstas están construídas tomando como base una dirección (la del primer carácter) y un marcador de fin de cadena (el carácter '\0'). La declaración de un puntero de caracter sigue las reglas habituales:

```
char * puntero_caracter;
```

Punteros de cadenas: Definición, Declaración e Iniciación. 
La declaración de una cadena puede ser de la forma siguiente:

```
char cadena[LONGITUD];
```

Así se reserva espacio para una cadena de LONGITUD caracteres.

En C, el nombre de las listas monodimensionales equivale a la dirección del primer elemento de las mismas. 
Una vez que se dispone de espacio reservado para la cadena, se puede construir un puntero de la cadena empleando las sentencias siguientes:

```
char * p;
char cadena[LONGITUD];
p = cadena;/* Esto equivale, desde luego, a poner: */
p = &cadena[0];
```

Ref.

http://maxus.fis.usal.es/fichas_c.web/07xx_PAGS/0702.html

Answer (score 2):

Los punteros a char acceden a cadenas de caracteres con la dirección del 1er elemento de la cadena, esa cadena termina con `'\0'` (carácter de fin de cadena). Cuando haces `++` se avanza a la siguiente dirección de la cadena (siguiente carácter).

Los arreglos de char son un apuntador al 1er carácter de la cadena. Por lo tanto, desde el punto de vista de como se almacenan en memoria no hay diferencia. La diferencia esta en la sintaxis, y ahí el usar sintaxis tipo arreglo es mejor, porque al usar sintaxis de puntero el compilador debe resolver la sobrecarga del operador `*` ya que también se usa para multiplicaciones y eso afecta un poco el rendimiento en la ejecución y compilación.

Además usar arreglos es mas sencillo para el ojo humano. La sintaxis es mas entendible con arreglos que con punteros.