# ¿Como declarar una cadena de caracteres para una variable dentro de un struct en C?

Tags: c

Estoy creando un struct con datos de un salon de clases que se declaran por el usuario en consola.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ID 0
#define TOTAL  3 //total de alumnos en el salon

struct alumno_programacion 
{
    int id_matricula;
    char *nombre; //<- problema 
    int edad;
    int telefono;
    float nota_final;
};

void definir_alumno(struct alumno_programacion *alu,int *n);

int main()
{
    int n = ID; //contador id_alumnos
    struct alumno_programacion salon[TOTAL]; 

    for (int i = 0;i<TOTAL;i++)
    {
        printf("------------Nuevo alumno (%d)-----------\n",i);
        definir_alumno(&salon[i],&n);
    }

    printf("\n-------------------RESUMEN ALUMNOS-------------------");
    for (int i = 0;i<TOTAL;i++)
    {
        printf("\nId matricula: %d\nNombre: %s\nEdad: %d\nTelefono: %d\nNota final: %.3f\n",
               salon[i].id_matricula, salon[i].nombre, salon[i].edad, salon[i].telefono,salon[i].nota_final);
    }

    return 0;
}

void definir_alumno(struct alumno_programacion *alu, int *n)
{
    char entrada_nom[20];
    int entrada_edad;
    int entrada_telefono;
    float entrada_nota_final;

    alu->id_matricula = *n;
    *n += 1;

    printf("ingrese nombre\n");
    scanf("%s",&entrada_nom); //<- problema 
    alu->nombre = entrada_nom; //<- problema 

    printf("ingrese edad\n");
    scanf("%d",&entrada_edad);
    alu->edad = entrada_edad;

    printf("ingrese telefono\n");
    scanf("%d",&entrada_telefono);
    alu->telefono = entrada_telefono;

    printf("Ingrese nota final\n");
    scanf("%f",&entrada_nota_final);
    alu->nota_final = entrada_nota_final;
}
```

el programa funciona bien para todos los datos excepto el nombre,
bien pues no tengo bien entendido del todo el tema de punteros pero tengo un problema con la forma en que obtengo los datos, he utilizado scanf() para el proceso ya que se me hacia el mas util, y no logro implementar correctamente fgets() por la transformación de tipos, he estado un rato intentando resolver.

```
-------------------RESUMEN ALUMNOS-------------------
Id matricula: 0
Nombre:  �2N�
Edad: 40
Telefono: 99999999
Nota final: 7.000

Id matricula: 1
Nombre:  �2N�
Edad: 21
Telefono: 88888888
Nota final: 4.000

Id matricula: 2
Nombre:  �2N�
Edad: 15
Telefono: 77777777
Nota final: 2.000
```

acaso alu->nombre esta almacenando una dirección de memoria?,se observa que todos los nombres poseen los mismos caracteres a pesar de haber ingresado nombres diferentes.

adicionalmente, al compilar da este warning

```
struct_alumno.c: In function ‘definir_alumno’:
struct_alumno.c:48:13: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[20]’ [-Wformat=]
   48 |     scanf("%s",&entrada_nom);
      |            ~^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |             |  |
      |             |  char (*)[20]
      |             char *
```

he intenado declarar char nombre; (sin puntero) y aun asi no me da resultados correctos.

Comment: Leer cadenas con `scanf` puede ser inseguro. Leer este [hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/383853/105299).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema real que estás teniendo es que cuando haces:

```
 alu->nombre = entrada_nom;
```

Estás haciendo referencia a la variable local `entrada_nom` qué solo existe en el scope de la función, una vez que sales de ella su valor se pierde y los punteros de todos tus `struct` quedan apuntando a basura (que es lo que ves cuando imprimes y encuentras caracteres extraños).

Recuerda que al declarar un puntero defines un método de acceso a un lugar en memoria PERO no asignas este espacio, de hecho puedes dejar el puntero apuntando a `null` y luego asignarlo. Necesitas definir dónde vas a guardar los datos.

Mira esta demostración en donde defino `entrada_nom` como una variable estática para que el compilador la mantenga y no la recicle cuando sales de la función.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define ID 0
#define TOTAL  3 //total de alumnos en el salon

struct alumno_programacion 
{
    int id_matricula;
    char *nombre; //<- problema 
    int edad;
    int telefono;
    float nota_final;
};

void definir_alumno(struct alumno_programacion *alu,int *n);

int main()
{
    int n = ID; //contador id_alumnos
    struct alumno_programacion salon[TOTAL]; 

    for (int i = 0;i<TOTAL;i++)
    {
        printf("------------Nuevo alumno (%d)-----------\n",i);
        definir_alumno(&salon[i],&n);
    }

    printf("\n-------------------RESUMEN ALUMNOS-------------------");
    for (int i = 0;i<TOTAL;i++)
    {
        printf("\nId matricula: %d\nNombre: %s\nEdad: %d\nTelefono: %d\nNota final: %.3f\n",
               salon[i].id_matricula, salon[i].nombre, salon[i].edad, salon[i].telefono,salon[i].nota_final);
    }

    return 0;
}

void definir_alumno(struct alumno_programacion *alu, int *n)
{
    static char entrada_nom[20];
    int entrada_edad;
    int entrada_telefono;
    float entrada_nota_final;

    alu->id_matricula = *n;
    *n += 1;

    printf("ingrese nombre\n");
    scanf("%s",&entrada_nom); //<- problema 
    alu->nombre = entrada_nom; //<- problema 

    printf("ingrese edad\n");
    scanf("%d",&entrada_edad);
    alu->edad = entrada_edad;

    printf("ingrese telefono\n");
    scanf("%d",&entrada_telefono);
    alu->telefono = entrada_telefono;

    printf("Ingrese nota final\n");
    scanf("%f",&entrada_nota_final);
    alu->nota_final = entrada_nota_final;
}
```

En la demostración tu puntero ahora apunta esta variable que no es reciclada y mantiene su valor, por lo tanto, todas tus estructuras apuntan al mismo lugar (tienen el mismo valor). Lo cuál tampoco es deseable, porque has asignado solo UN LUGAR en dónde guardar TODOS tus nombres y cuando imprimes los nombres verás que todos son iguales (al menos ahora no son datos basura).

De aquí podemos deducir también que si lo que vas a usar es un puntero en tus `struct` necesitas tener un lugar estático en donde guardar tus datos. Y por lo que veo en tu aplicación, ese lugar debería de ser tu misma estructura y por lo tanto deberíamos de tener una array de caracteres (string) en la misma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ID 0
#define TOTAL  3 //total de alumnos en el salon

struct alumno_programacion 
{
    int id_matricula;
    int edad;
    int telefono;
    float nota_final;
    char nombre[20]; 
};

void definir_alumno(struct alumno_programacion *alu,int *n);

int main()
{
    int n = ID; //contador id_alumnos
    struct alumno_programacion salon[TOTAL]; 

    for (int i = 0;i<TOTAL;i++)
    {
        printf("------------Nuevo alumno (%d)-----------\n",i);
        definir_alumno(&salon[i],&n);
    }

    printf("\n-------------------RESUMEN ALUMNOS-------------------");
    for (int i = 0;i<TOTAL;i++)
    {
        printf("\nId matricula: %d\nNombre: %s\nEdad: %d\nTelefono: %d\nNota final: %.3f\n",
               salon[i].id_matricula, salon[i].nombre, salon[i].edad, salon[i].telefono,salon[i].nota_final);
    }

    return 0;
}

void definir_alumno(struct alumno_programacion *alu, int *n)
{
    int entrada_edad;
    int entrada_telefono;
    float entrada_nota_final;

    alu->id_matricula = *n;
    *n += 1;

    printf("ingrese nombre\n");
    scanf("%s",alu->nombre); //<- problema 

    printf("ingrese edad\n");
    scanf("%d",&entrada_edad);
    alu->edad = entrada_edad;


    printf("ingrese telefono\n");
    scanf("%d",&entrada_telefono);
    alu->telefono = entrada_telefono;

    printf("Ingrese nota final\n");
    scanf("%f",&entrada_nota_final);
    alu->nota_final = entrada_nota_final;
}
```

Mira como hago utilizo directamente el `scanf` sobre la dirección del array de la estructura, porque ya tenemos un lugar en dónde guardarla.

¡Espero que esto te sea de ayuda! ¡Suerte programando!

Comment: Muuuchas gracias, y bien declarar scanf("%s",alu->nombre); pero para las siguientes variables enteras (edad,telefono,etc...) de modo que sea  scanf("%d",alu->edad) no funcionaria ya que char nombre[20] es considerado un puntero y las otras son solo variables enteras?

Comment: Si funciona, porque de igual manera lo que haces es que pasas la dirección(puntero) de donde están los datos de tu estructura,  `scanf` funciona con un puntero, tendrías que hacer por ejemplo algo cómo: `scanf("%d",&alu->edad);`

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en tu estructura estás guardando un puntero pero puntero que termina apuntando a basura.

Analicemos tu codigo: dentro de la función `definir_alumno` creas una variable `char entrada_nom[20]` en la cual guardas el valor ingresado por el usuario. Después, asignas la dirección de memoria de `entrada_nom` al puntero de tu estructura. Sin embargo, al salir de la función `definir_alumno`, el scope de `entrada_nom` se ha terminado por lo que ya no existe más y el puntero dentro de tu estructura se ha quedado apuntando a algo que ya no existe (basura).

Para solucionar este problema, tendrías que reemplazar en tu estructura `char*` por `char[20]` y de esa manera guardar el valor directamente en la estructura, sin utilizar un apuntador de intermediario.

```
struct alumno_programacion 
{
    int id_matricula;
    char nombre[20];
    int edad;
    int telefono;
    float nota_final;
};

void definir_alumno(struct alumno_programacion *alu,int *n);

int main()
{
    int n = ID; //contador id_alumnos
    struct alumno_programacion salon[TOTAL]; 

    for (int i = 0;i<TOTAL;i++)
    {
        printf("------------Nuevo alumno (%d)-----------\n",i);
        definir_alumno(&salon[i],&n);
    }

    printf("\n-------------------RESUMEN ALUMNOS-------------------");
    for (int i = 0;i<TOTAL;i++)
    {
        printf("\nId matricula: %d\nNombre: %s\nEdad: %d\nTelefono: %d\nNota final: %.3f\n", salon[i].id_matricula, salon[i].nombre, salon[i].edad, salon[i].telefono,salon[i].nota_final);
    }

    return 0;
}

void definir_alumno(struct alumno_programacion *alu, int *n)
{
    // Estas variables no son necesarias
    //char entrada_nom[20];
    //int entrada_edad;
    //int entrada_telefono;
    //float entrada_nota_final;

    alu->id_matricula = *n;
    *n += 1;

    printf("ingrese nombre\n");
    scanf("%s",alu->nombre);
    //alu->nombre = entrada_nom; //<- problema 

    printf("ingrese edad\n");
    scanf("%d",&alu->edad);
    //alu->edad = entrada_edad;

    printf("ingrese telefono\n");
    scanf("%d",&alu->telefono);
    //alu->telefono = entrada_telefono;

    printf("Ingrese nota final\n");
    scanf("%f",&alu->nota_final);
    //alu->nota_final = entrada_nota_final;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, acabo de asimilar el codigo, scanf("%f",&alu->nota_final) es mucho mejor el anterior, sin embargo me surge la duda, ¿es equivalente, &alu->nota_final a &*alu.nota_final ?

Comment: Sí pero tienes que utilizar paréntesis: &(*alu).nota_final. Básicamente, es la dirección de memoria del miembro nota_final de la estructura a la que apunta el puntero alu.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema radica en que el tipo de variable `char *` y `char[]` son tratados de forma diferente. En la declaración de tu struct defines la variable nombre de tipo `char *` , mientras que en la función `definir_alumno()` declaras la variable `entrada_nom` de tipo `char[20]`.

Creo que el problema se debería solucionar si en tu función `definir_alumno()` cambias el tipo de la variable `entrada_nom` a `char *`.

Si quieres saber mas sobre la diferencia entre `char *` y `char []` visita [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23186/cual-es-la-diferencia-entre-char-name-y-char-name-en-c).

Espero te haya servido. Un saludo.

Comment: La pregunta que mencionas hace referencia a la declaración y asignación simultanea de una variable, cómo algún tipo de variable constante. En esa misma respuesta se lee en la conclusión *"Si vas a modificar la cadena debes usar el array."*, lo cuál es lo que sucede en este caso, el usuario declara la variable y luego la edita utilizando `scanf`` para guardar el valor que digita el usuario. Mi intención no es desmotivarte, es aclararte el porqué esto no responde al problema del OP, aun así es una buena observación y tu respuesta tiene un muy buen formato.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración. La verdad no estaba muy seguro de mi respuesta, intentare ser mas atento la próxima vez.

Comment: Creo que tu intención es lo más importante, yo siempre corro los códigos de los OP en está [página](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler), aplico mis correcciones y veo si arreglan el problema. Así tendrás toda la seguridad en tu respuesta si soluciona o no ¡Espero que te sirva!

Comment: No conocía esa pagina, puede serme muy útil, la utilizare de ahora en adelante. Muchas gracias!